# Matlab: How can I pass a TCPIP handle to a parfeval worker/ How to make parfeval worker works under same workspace

Tags: matlab, handle, tcp, parfor

In my case, I need to construct a TCPIP handle before running the parfeval. So I was thinking to pass the TCPIP handle to parfeval. However, it looks like the worker runs under a different workspace than the workspace where TCPIP handle I was constructed. Any idea how to solve this problem ? Thanks

Main code:

```
port = tcpip('192.xxx.xx.xx', xxx); 
fopen(port);
Request_message = ['aaaaaa'];
fwrite(port, Request_message );

value = []; 
parpool(2)
for i = 1:20
   f1 = parfeval(@f1_worker,1,port);
   if ~isempty(value)
     f2 = parfeval(@f2_worker,1,value);
   end
[completedIdx,value] = fetchNext([f1]);
end
fclose(port);
delete(port);
delete(gcp('nocreate'));
```

f1 woker:

```
function  [message] = f1_worker(port)    
  message =  fread(port);
end
```